# Cordova FileEntry can't return File -> FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR

Tags: javascript, file, cordova, fileapi

I'm trying to get a file from iOS filesystem.
My file is located at:

```
console.log(PATH);
--> file:///var/mobile/Applications/B816F30B-791A-43E5-B33A-A26075E8B585/Documents/123123123.wav
```

Now I'm trying to get the `File` via File API

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(PATH, function(fileEntry){
    console.log(fileEntry.fullPath); // /var/mobile/Applications/B816F30B-791A-43E5-B33A-A26075E8B585/Documents/123123123.wav
    console.log(fileEntry.name); // 123123123.wav
    console.log(fileEntry.toURL()); cdvfile://localhost/temporary/var/mobile/Applications/B816F30B-791A-43E5-B33A-A26075E8B585/Documents/123123123.wav

    fileEntry.file(function(file){
        // do stuff
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

The `FileEntry` was found but when I call `file()` I get a `FileError` that looks like this:

```
[Log] FileError (main.js, line 15569)
    code: 1
    __proto__: FileError
```

ErrorCode 1 is: NOT_FOUND_ERR.

Why do I get a NOT_FOUND_ERR when the `FileEntry` was found and the logging looks ok ?

Answer (score 0):

This is my implimentation:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {
    console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);

    fs.root.getFile(fileName, {}, function (fileEntry) {
        console.log("fileEntry is file?" + fileEntry.isFile.toString());
        fileEntry.file(function (file) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function (evt) {
                return success(evt.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });

    }, function (e) {
        throw JSON.stringify(e);
    });

}, function (e) {
    throw JSON.stringify(e);
});
```

You can adapt this to use your URL.